# What's the most DRY way to disable a link to the current page?

Tags: django, jinja2

In my Django web-app, I want to let users sort model objects by different parameters, which I achieve with URL parameters which tell the view which items should be loaded. Here's the Jinja/HTML snippet from the template:

```
<p><b><span class="text-info">sort by:</span></b>
                    <a href="{% url 'artists' %}">latest_release</a> |
                    <a href="{% url 'artists'%}?sorted_by=name">alphabetically</a> |
                <a href="{% url 'artists'%}?sorted_by=next_release">soonest release</a></p>
```

If the user is already sorting by `latest_release` (the first link), I want the link from it removed. However, I can't seem to find a way to do this in a DRY way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define dict in your view with argument name - display name mapping:

```
mapping = {'': 'latest_release', 'name': 'alphabetically', 'next_release': 'soonest release'}
```

and pass it to context:

```
context['mapping'] = mapping
```

Now in template iterate over each pair from dict and show link only if `sorted_by` value not equal with key:

```
{% for k, v in mapping.items %}
    {% if request.GET.sorted_by|default:"" != k %} <a href="{% url 'artists' %}?sorted_by={{ k }}">{{ v }}</a> |{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

To remove `|` delimiter after last link you can validate [`forloop.last`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) status.

Comment: I'm sure this answer has *conceptually* the right idea, the problem is - there are two instances when objects are sorted by `latest release`, one is when the path is: `/artists/?sorted_by=` and the other is when it's `/artists/`. In the latter case, the link isn't disabled. For some reason removing the `artists` from my [urls.py](https://pastebin.com/F1jWLcZe) always returns an error.

Comment: @zerohedge `{% if request.GET.sorted_by and request.GET.sorted_by != k %}` condition shoudl work for both cases. Actually you dont need second urlpattern `url(r'^artists/(?P<sorted_by>.*)/$', views.artists, name='artists'),` remove it. Since you pass sorted_by with request argument, not url agument.

Comment: tried this, if the URL doesn't include a parameter at all (`/artists/`), then none of the pages are marked as links. Do I need to specify this case manually? I may have no explained this but the default sort (on URL `/artists`) is by latest release.

Comment: @zerohedge so the problem is when you open `/artists/` you see all links? Even `latest release`?

Comment: I see no links at all. because `if request.GET.sorted_by` evaluates to `False` and so everything is printed as `<p>`'s.

Comment: @zerohedge Ah, try `request.GET.sorted_by|default:""` as condition. Check updated answer.

Comment: Brilliant! now I only need to understand the logic behind this (and also understand how on earth can I give up on the URL conf setting with the parameter!). Thanks!

Comment: @zerohedge you can find information about default filter here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#default